# XPATH Syntax - Katalon Studio

Tags: groovy, cucumber, katalon-studio

**Hi,**
I wanted to get the text from the webpage with Cucumber & Groovy in Katalon Studio. Please find the below Step Definition which has the xpath and below is the html code.
I wanted to read the below two lines from the page which can be referred in the html code also below. The number 596 varies each time i.e., dynamic.

Create Inquiry Tracking # 596
The inquiry for system tracking # 596 has been submitted successfully

**Step Definition**
inquiryt1 = WebUI.getText(findTestObject(By.xpath("//td[@class='pageTitle'][1]")))

**Full Page HTML :**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Govt Inquiry</title>   

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/en/css/uitmpl.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/gmpinquiry/css/gmpinquiry.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/js/other_scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/js/freezingHeader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/js/sortTable.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <style>
        table.mQH {display:block;}
    </style>
</noscript>
<style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (self === top) {
       var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
       antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
   } else {
       top.location = self.location;
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="uitmpl_qhPageInit()">

<!-- Skip To Main Content should be the next element immediately after body element -->
 <div class="skipnav"><a href="#maincontent" title="Skip to Main Content">Skip to Main Content</a> </div>














<script type="text/javascript" src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/js/menu_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/js/application_settings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/js/global_settings.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
application.data = {

td_1: "Home",
td_2: "Govt Inquiry",
td_3: "Create Inquiry",
td_4: "Reports/Search",
td_5: "My Preference",

url_1: "javascript:OnGMPPortalSubmit(document.frmMenuScr, '')",
url_2: "javascript:OnMenuSubmit (document.frmMenuScr, 'homepage')",
url_3: "javascript:OnMenuDispatch (document.frmMenuScr, 'setupinquiry','create')",
url_4: "javascript:OnMenuSubmit (document.frmMenuScr, 'inqsubmenu')",
url_5: "javascript:OnMenuSubmit (document.frmMenuScr, 'userpref')"

};

global.data = {
//td_1: "AT&amp;T BusinessDirect",
td_1: "Write Us",
td_2: "Help <span class=\"offscrn\"> - Opens a PDF Document for Help</span>",
td_3: "Close",
//td_3_1: "General Help",
//td_3_2: "Application Tutorial",
//td_3_3: "<span id=\"shHd\">Show</span> Quick Help",
//url_1: "javascript:bizDirect()",
url_1: "javascript:OnMenuSubmit(document.frmMenuScr, 'compose')",
url_2: "javascript:uitmpl_popUpReg(document.frmMenuScr.action + '?appId=' + document.frmMenuScr.appId.value + '&flName=' + document.frmMenuScr.context.value + '/help/Inquiry_UG.pdf')",
url_3: "javascript:window.close();"
//url_3_1: "javascript:uitmpl_popUpReg(document.frmMenuScr.action + \\'?appId=\\' + document.frmMenuScr.appId.value + \\'&flName=\\' + document.frmMenuScr.context.value + \\'/help/Inquiry_UG.pdf\\')",
//url_3_2: "#",
//url_3_3: "javascript:uitmpl_qhPageToggle()"
};
</script>





<script type="text/javascript" src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/gmpinquiry/js/script.js"></script>


<!--************ uitmplbegin: tBAN ************-->
<!--****** begin:background graphic ******-->
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tBAN">

    <tr>
        <td><img src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/en/img/swoosh.gif" width="650" height="69" alt="" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--****** end:background graphic ******-->

<!--****** begin:logo and company title ******-->
<div class="logoCompany">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tBAN">

    <tr>
        <td class="logo"><img src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/en/img/attbizdirect.gif" width="291" height="63" alt="AT&T | Business Direct" border="0" /></td>
        <td><!-- stretchable cell --></td>
        <!-- max characters for company title: 72 w/ breaks (24 per line) -->
        <td class="company">ATT Gov Sol Dev<br/>rm0013 

      <!-- Begin Skip Top Navigation -->
      <!-- <div class="skipnav"><a href="#main" title="Skip to Main Content">Skip to Main Content</a></div> -->
      <!-- End Skip Top Navigation --></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<!--****** end:logo and company title ******-->

<!--****** begin:application title ******-->
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" class="appTitle">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:OnMenuSubmit (document.frmMenuScr, 'homepage')">View and Analyze Govt. Bills: Govt Inquiry</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--****** end:application title ******-->

<!--************ uitmplend: tBAN ************-->
<!--************ uitmplbegin: tNAV ************-->
<div id="glbl">
<script language="JavaScript1.3">
<!--
uitmpl_list("global");
//-->
</script>
<noscript>
<div class="globalAcc">
<table class="global_main" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td class="global_main_spacer">&nbsp;</td>
<td><a href="javascript:bizDirect()">AT&amp;T BusinessDirect</a></td><td class="pipe">|</td><td><a href="javascript:OnMenuSubmit(document.frmMenuScr, 'compose')" target="_new">Write Us</a></td><td class="pipe">|</td><td><a href="#">Help</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</noscript>
</div>
<div id="app">
<script language="JavaScript1.3">
<!--
uitmpl_list("application");
//-->
</script>
<noscript>
<div class="applicationAcc"><table class="application_main" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td><a href="javascript:OnMenuSubmit (document.frmMenuScr, 'homepage')">Home</a></td>
<td class="pipe">|</td>
<td><a href="javascript:alert ('Under Construction...')">Create/Update Dispute</a></td>
<td class="pipe">|</td>
<td><a href="javascript:alert ('Under Construction...')">Reports/Search</a></td>
<td class="pipe">|</td>
<td><a href="javascript:OnMenuSubmit (document.frmMenuScr, 'UserPreference')">My Preference</a></td>
<td class="pipe">|</td>
<td><a href="javascript:alert ('Under Construction...')">User Management</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</noscript>
</div>
<!--************ uitmplend: tNAV ************-->
<form name="frmMenuScr" action="/servlet/GMPGate" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="appId" value="gmpinquiry">
<input type="hidden" name="nextScr" value="userpref">
<input type="hidden" name="methodToCall" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="context" value="/gmpinquiry"/>


</form>



<!--***** begin:grid *****-->
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrap">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" class="grid">
            <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="PageHeader" -->
            <!--************ uitmplbegin: tPH ************-->
            <!--****** begin:titles ******-->
            <table cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tPH">
                <!--****** begin:page title ******-->
                <tr>
                    <td class="pageTitle">Create Inquiry Tracking # 599</td>
                </tr>
                <!--****** end:page title ******-->
            </table>
            <!--****** end:titles ******-->
            <!--************ uitmplend: tPH ************-->
            <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
        </td>
        <td width="182" class="grid"><img src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/en/img/pixel.gif" width="182" height="1" alt="" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--***** end:grid *****-->

<!--***** begin:grid *****-->
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrap">
    <tr>

<td width="100%" class="grid"> 
<!--- BeginOptional name="TaskConfirmation" --->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="TaskConfirmation" -->
<!--************ uitmplbegin: mTC ************-->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" class="mTC">
<tr class="msgConfirm"> 
<td> <img src="?appId=gmpinquiry&flName=/uitmpl/en/img/confirmation.gif" width="29" height="29" 
        border="0" alt="Confirmation." /></td><td>The inquiry for system tracking # 599 has been submitted successfully. </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**REASON FOR FAILED WITH THE SOLUTION**

```
2019-06-26 18:40:10.049 ERROR c.k.k.c.c.keyword.CucumberReporter   
- ❌ it should displays create inquiry pages FAILED.

    Reason:
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject() 
        is applicable for argument types: (org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath) values: [By.xpath: //td[@class='pageTitle'][1]]

        Possible solutions: findTestObject(java.lang.String), findTestObject(java.lang.String, java.util.Map) at CreateInquiry001.it_should_displays_create_inquiry_page2(CreateInquiry001.groovy:369)
                at ✽.it should displays create inquiry pages(C:/Users/vdavuluri2/Katalon Studio/Govt Inquiry/Include/features/Create Inquiry-001.feature:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Katalon's `findTestObject()` method is used for selecting an object from the object repository. It doesn't work with `By` class.

You can try with something like the following: create an object with the given Xpath and then use `WebUI.getText()` on it:

```
TestObject testObject = new TestObject().addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, "//td[@class='pageTitle'][1]")
WebUI.getText(testObject)
```

Comment: **Appreciate your help, Mate Mrse.** It works with TestObject.  THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

The element with class pageTitle looks unique so why not user
//td[@class='pageTitle']

Comment: Thank You for the reply.                                                                                         inquirytext = WebUI.getText(findTestObject(By.xpath('//td[@class='pageTitle'])))   Does it look fine ? I am new using the XPATH.

Comment: If it doesn't, try ```//td[@class='pageTitle'][1]```. The xpath may return multiple items so you need to choose the first one.

Comment: I have posted the test result at the bottom of the original post. can you please look into that and suggest to proceed further ? It looks it is returning an error - inquiryt1 = WebUI.getText(findTestObject(By.xpath("//td[@class='pageTitle'][1]")))  Please check this line !!

Comment: I have added the Full Page of my HTML Code.. which I have not shared earlier. Appreciate your help.